# Wall sliding on collision detection

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I have some wall collision detection, instead of setting both playerX and playerY co-ords to the previous co-ords on collison which completely jolts my player. I want the walls to have a sliding effect. The code I have seems to work apart from on 0, 90, 180, and 270 degrees. When I am sliding and i change my player angle whilst sliding, once on of these four angles is hit, sliding will not continue and the player will stay static until no collision is found. Basically the sliding stops whatever angle you are at

```
if (wallCollision() == true) {

    if (playerAngle >  0 && playerAngle < 90){
        playerY = prevY;
    }
    else if (playerAngle >90 && playerAngle < 180){
        playerX = prevX;
    }
    else if (playerAngle > 180 && playerAngle < 270){
        playerY = prevY;
    }
    else if (playerAngle >270 && playerAngle < 360){
        playerX = prevX;
    }
    else {
        playerX = prevX;
        playerY = prevY;
    }

}
```

edit I added else if's

My issue is once a player hits either 0 90 180 or 270 degrees on sliding the detection stops working and the player goes through

Comment: So what is your question? Is it not behaving as expected? Are there errors? By the way, your `else` case is only corresponding to the very last `if`, which is probably the cause of your problem

Comment: updated my question a little basically my detection breaks on 0 90 180 or 270 once detected

Comment: Did you add those else ifs after reading Cyber's comment? If so did it fix your problem? Because if those were just if statements, that was the problem.

Comment: Did you try making all the `<` into `<=`? Because your if-statements have "holes" at exactly 0, 90, 180, 270 and 360 degrees. You might say that you shouldn't compare-equal for floating point numbers, and that's correct, but you shouldn't have "holes" either, especially if there is a chance that your code is actually causing the values to move towards those "holes", which is what I think is happening here.

Comment: I did add the else if's after Cybers comment. didn't fix it and adding he <= made things worse so the code i have is the current code im using.